# Как в java внести значения в таблицу Mysql через переменные

Tags: java, jdbc

Использую jdbc в intellij для работы с mysql. Создал подключение

```
private static void DatabaseConnection(int idValue, String nameValue){
    Connection connection;

    try {
        Driver driver = new FabricMySQLDriver();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute("INSERT INTO category(ID, NAME) VALUES ()");

        if (!connection.isClosed()){
            System.out.println("Соединение с базой данных установлено");
        }
        connection.close();
        if (connection.isClosed()){
            System.out.println("Соединение с базой данных закрыто");
        }
    }catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Ошибка загрузки класса драйвера");
    }
}
```

И не знаю как ввести значения в таблицу с помощью переменных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте PreparedStatement, вот для примера

```
String query = "INSERT INTO category(ID, NAME) VALUES (?,?)";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement( query  );
statement.setLong( 1,123 );
statement.setString( 2,"AAA" );
statement.execute();
```

Comment: В values() добавить переменные?

Comment: собственно знаки вопроса и есть переменные. Потом вы каждой переменной указываете значение `statement.setLong( 1,123 );`

Comment: мне нужно добавить атрибуты класса idValue и nameValue, чтобы это не было жостко закодировано, каждый раз при вызове метода добавлялся новый ряд

Comment: так и подставляйте `statement.setLong( 1, idValue ); statement.setString( 2, nameValue );`

Comment: @АртёмКурилко если ответ полезен голосуйте за стрелками слева и закрывайте вопрос, если нет -  опишите что не получается.

Comment: окей, просто произошла ошибка с mysql и так и не могу добраться до этого момента

Comment: Что пишет mysql?

Comment: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. сделал как они сказали в конце url поставил ?useSSL=false, но теперь просто выбивает ошибку невозможно подключиться к базе данных

Comment: в командной строке пишет отказ в доступе юзеру odbc@localhost, но могу зайти через root

Comment: посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189756/warning-about-ssl-connection-when-connecting-to-mysql-database

Comment: да, уже проверял эту ссылку, не помогло